# bootstrap colorpicker change class color

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to use Bootstrap Colorpicker (http://mjolnic.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/)  to change the color of some text, but newbie so not able to implement it.

```
    $('.pickthecolor').colorpicker().on('changeColor.colorpicker', function(event){
     $('.headingexample').css("color", "red"); 
});
```

is working as expected. 
Documentation suggest:

```
        $('.my-colorpicker').colorpicker().on('changeColor.colorpicker', function(event){
          bodyStyle.backgroundColor = event.color.toHex();
        });
```

How can I combine these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
$('.pickthecolor').colorpicker().on('changeColor.colorpicker', function(event){
    $('.headingexample').css("color", event.color.toHex()); 
});
```